# What does it mean to have Azure service tagged with (Preview) ? is it okay to start using it for production releases?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I was reading and found a very nice service in Azure called "Azure Container Apps", but i found it in (Preview).
What does it mean, like i have some doubts:

- Can i consider this for a production releases ?
- Does it affect the SLA ?
- How long time is usually takes to stay in Preview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure offers preview features to you for evaluation purposes. A preview may include preview, beta, or other pre-release features, services, software, or regions. Previews are subject to reduced or different service terms, as set forth in your service agreement and the preview supplemental terms -https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/ . Previews are made available to you on the condition that you agree to these terms of use, which supplement your agreement governing the use of Azure.

It always safe and recommended to use previews only for testing or evaluating a service and not on productions, as they are not stable services and are subjected to change.

Comment: Thanks very much .. i think i need to check the road map or the release date of the service then decide if that will work with us

Answer (score 2):

> Azure may include preview, beta, or other pre-release features, services, software, or regions offered by Microsoft ("Previews"). Previews are licensed to you as part of your agreement governing use of Azure.
>
> Pursuant to the terms of your Azure subscription, PREVIEWS ARE PROVIDED "AS-IS," "WITH ALL FAULTS," AND "AS AVAILABLE," AND ARE EXCLUDED FROM THE SERVICE LEVEL AGREEMENTS AND LIMITED WARRANTY. Previews may not be covered by customer support. Previews may be subject to reduced or different security, compliance and privacy commitments, as further explained in the Microsoft Privacy Statement, Microsoft Azure Trust Center, the Product Terms, the DPA, and any additional notices provided with the Preview. The following terms in the DPA do not apply to Previews: Processing of Personal Data; GDPR, Data Security, and HIPAA Business Associate. Customers should not use Previews to process Personal Data or other data that is subject to heightened legal or regulatory requirements.
>
> Certain named Previews are subject to additional terms set forth below, if any. These Previews are made available to you pursuant to these additional terms, which supplement your agreement governing use of Azure. We may change or discontinue Previews at any time without notice. We also may choose not to release a Preview into "General Availability".

Source (and more information): [Supplemental Terms of Use for Microsoft Azure Previews](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/).

In short, to me the answers to your questions would be:

1. Yes, you can... however. It might mean you need to take into account that stuff might break or change and prepare for that.
2. It does (read above)
3. That completely depends on the service

If you want to stay up to date with services, Previews, General Availability and more, see [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/).

Some Preview services are more Preview than others. There have been Preview services in the past, where you could be pretty sure it would most probably propagate into it being a full blown Azure service in the future. And then there are services that are in early Preview that will probably have some big changes before moving to GA, if they are moving there at all.

As far as Container Apps goes: I think Microsoft hit a sweet spot between Kubernetes and App Services with Container Apps. I think chances of it *not* moving to general availability are close to zero.

Also, Microsoft Build is just around the corner (May 24th to 26th 2022). These are normally the times quite a few new Preview services are announced, or existing ones move to GA.

**EDIT:**
For a product roadmap on Azure Container Apps, please see its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps).

Comment: Thanks very much .. i think i need to check the road map or the release date of the service then decide if that will work with us

Answer (score 0):

Azure Container Apps is now generally available. No longer in preview: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-container-apps-general-availability/ba-p/3416885